# Comparisons data for typical language input speeds

Tags: data-request

I am looking for some statistical comparison data of typical input speed ranges of text input methods for English language in terms of characters per minute or words per minute comparing:

- voice typing
- typing at a regular full PC keyboard
- typing by swiping on phone keyboards such as gboard, Swype, and Swiftkey, using predictive text
- typing by swiping on phone keyboards such as gboard, Swype, and Swiftkey, without using predictive text
- typing in phone keyboards without swiping with two fingers, using predictive text
- typing in phone keyboards without swiping with two fingers, without using predictive text
- typing in phone keyboards without swiping with one finger, using predictive text
- typing in phone keyboards without swiping with one finger, without using predictive text

and anything else helpful, in terms of input methods and related information, including other languages, if known.

Thank you for your help.

[Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) and [Swype](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nuance.swype.trial) or [Swiftkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey)

Note, some resources on Google such as [this one](https://www.ratatype.com/learn/average-typing-speed/) and [this one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_per_minute?wprov=sfla1) list the average keyboard input speed at about 30wpm for texting whereas 40 wpm for keyboarding, but doesn't display the data I looking for.